# Angular Material Chips activated chip ngclass

Tags: angular, angular-material

There is a definition

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip 
    *ngFor="let chip of chips"
    [ngClass]="isActive(chip)"
    (click)="setActiveChip(chip)">
    {{ chip.name }}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

which has `isActive` function for setting chip active based on variable `cardId`:

```
isActive(chip) {
  const cardId = 2;
 
  if(cardId) {
     const activeChip = chip.id === cardId;
     return activeChip ? 'mat-chip-active' : '';
   }
 }
```

How to set ngClass to the other chip using another(`setActiveChip`) function?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/set-active-chip?file=app%2Fchips-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Don't use functions as a binding . It is not good for performance. It always listen page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/set-active-chip-nvg8no

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MatChipInputEvent } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: "chips-overview-example",
  templateUrl: "chips-overview-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["chips-overview-example.css"]
})
export class ChipsOverviewExample {

  chips = [
    { id: 1, name: "One" },
    { id: 2, name: "Two" },
    { id: 3, name: "Three" }
  ];
  // Set default to the 2nd chip
  activeChip = this.chips[1];

  setActiveChip(chip) {
    this.activeChip = chip;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip 
    *ngFor="let chip of chips"
    [ngClass]="{'mat-chip-active': activeChip === chip}"
    (click)="setActiveChip(chip)">
    {{ chip.name }}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: Using function for binding is bad approach for performance. use conditional class binding rather than function

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/set-active-chip-dnelu9 this is better approach

Comment: @pc_coder Update blitz to remove the function binding, i thought the main issue he want to help is the logic regarding setActive before. Thanks for point the issue.